# How to only show the menu in the main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu

I want to only show my menu in my main activity then have a back button from my other activities instead of a menu. Right now I am just wondering how would I would remove the menu from the action bar on the activities I don't want it on.

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Insulter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="Favourites"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="Settings"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance">
    </activity>


</application>
```

My menu opener inside my main activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent startSettings = (new Intent(Insulter.this,Settings.class));
        startActivity(startSettings);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.exit_the_app) {
        finish();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.favourites) {
        Intent startFavs = (new Intent(Insulter.this, Favourites.class));
        String[] objects = new String[favs.size()];
        favs.toArray(objects);
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objects));
        startFavs.putStringArrayListExtra("favs",list);
        startActivity(startFavs);
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Simple 'Do not attach menu' for other activities..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky I'm pretty new to this sorry where would I put this? In the manifest?

Comment: Just remove this method from your activity `onCreateOptionsMenu` ..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky But I want  it in my main activity just not my other activites this removes it from the main activity as well

Comment: As @tynn suggested return true for `MainActivity` and `false` for others..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want menu in any of your activity, then you need to override **onCreateOptionsMenu** and **onOptionsItemSelected**...
If you don't want menu, simply don't override these methods in your activity...

Comment: Cheers, I feel like this was the simplest solution, although in my other activities I only overrode  onCreateOptionsMenu. Is there any reason to override onOptionsItemSelected if there is no menu to click on?

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected() is for handling menu item  click.

Answer (score 2):

[Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) is the place where it gets created. Just don't override this method or let it return false to not show the menu.

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

If you're using the same implementation for all your activities, define a field `boolean isMain` and return it from onCreateOptionsMenu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    if (!isMain)
        return false;

    [creating the menu here like before]
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks just having a little trouble with the !isMain part should this be !is(my activity) or something more like (class == mainactivity)?

Comment: @James I don't know your implementation, so I can't realy suggest anything. But anything that works would do for you. Just use the information you already have to differentiate between the different activities.

Answer (score 0):

For each activity that you create, there must be a menu file associated with it in the `res/menu` folder. Simply delete or comment the corresponding `<item>` tags. You may experiment with them by looking at the output show in the preview screen.

Note: I think this works only when an activity is created automatically using the UI (i.e not manually) since the corresponding menu file is generated automatically with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following steps to **remove options menu** and **add back button** in your non-main activities --

1. Don't override onCreateOptionsMenu method.
2. call **getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)** in your activity's onCreate method.
3. Override onOptionsItemSelected method in following way--

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch(item.getItemId()) {
       case android.R.id.home:
           finish();
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
   ```